# D3 - position text labels on centered to origin movable axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart that has its axes centered at the origin (0,0). When I pan or zoom around, the axes should stay at the origin unless it goes out of view, in which case the axes are to be restricted to the boundary edges of the chart.

I need the text labels to follow along with those axes and remain in view along the edges of the screen if either axis goes off-screen. The behavior I'm going for is much like with desmos.com text labels on the graph as you pan around they remain on-screen along the edges.

I had to resort to removing original axes by setting opacity to 0 and creating two lines to act as the axes.

Here's the (kind of pseudo) code for positioning the horizontal labels for each vertical grid line, but I don't know how to translate it to d3.js

```
/* THIS CODE INSIDE zoomed function */

/* get position/value of (0,**y**) of origin */
var y = newY(0)

for each label {

    /* get current label bounding box */
    var bb = label.getBBox();

    /* get labels x position */
    var x = label.getX();

    if (y < 0){ /* if < than 0 (top of chart)*/
        /* label will be positioned at top of the screen */
        y = bb.height;
    } else if (y >= height - bb.height){
        /* label will be positioned at bottom of the screen */
        y = height;
    } else {
        /* label will be positioned somewhere in the middle of the screen */
        y = y + bb.height;
    }

    /* draw new label at x and y values or change current labels position */
    svg.append("text")
           .attr("x", x)
           .attr("y", y)
       .text(/* tick value here */)
}
```

and here is the code I have so far for this example

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
      }

      .container {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px grey solid;
      }

      g.grid .tick line {
        stroke: lightgrey !important;
      }

      .d3-axis {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function clamp(value, min, max) {
      return Math.min(Math.max(value, Math.min(min, max)), Math.max(min, max));
    }

    const Plot = function Plot(container) {
      var width = 350,
        height = 350;

      var svg = d3
        .select(container)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      var zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoomed);

      var x = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 5])
        .range([-1, width + 1]);

      var y = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([5, 0])
        .range([-1, height + 1]);

      var xTicks = d3
        .axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(((width + 2) / (height + 2)) * 10)
        .tickSize(height)
        .tickPadding(8 - height);

      var yTicks = d3
        .axisRight(y)
        .ticks(10)
        .tickSize(width)
        .tickPadding(8 - width);

      var gX = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "grid-x")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(xTicks)
        .call((g) =>
          g.select(".domain").attr("opacity", 0)
        ); /* hide axis line */

      var gY = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "grid-y")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(yTicks)
        .call((g) => g.select(".domain").attr("opacity", 0));

      svg
        .append("line")
        .attr("id", "ax-line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", height / 2)
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", height / 2)
        .attr("class", "d3-axis");

      svg
        .append("line")
        .attr("id", "ay-line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", height / 2)
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", height / 2)
        .attr("class", "d3-axis");

      svg.call(zoom);

      function zoomed() {
        var newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
        var newY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y);

        gX.call(xTicks.scale(newX));
        gY.call(yTicks.scale(newY));

        svg
          .select("#ax-line")
          .attr("x1", 0)
          .attr("y1", clamp(newY(0), 1, height))
          .attr("x2", width)
          .attr("y2", clamp(newY(0), 1, height));

        svg
          .select("#ay-line")
          .attr("x1", clamp(newX(0), 1, width))
          .attr("y1", 0)
          .attr("x2", clamp(newX(0), 1, width))
          .attr("y2", height);
      }
    };

    let container = document.querySelector(".container");

    let plot = Plot(container);
  </script>
</html>
```

Ideal output (axes labels, following the axis center lines themselves):

[image]

UPDATE: managed to get the text on the horizontal axis aligned, but it's still a little bit buggy and the code is very crude and probably inefficient. The grid lines overlap the text, so it seems like the text labels need to be drawn after all the grid lines which I don't know how to do.

```
function zoomed() {
  var newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
  var newY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y);

  gX.call(xTicks.scale(newX));
  gY.call(yTicks.scale(newY));

  svg
    .select("#ax-line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", clamp(newY(0), 1, height))
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", clamp(newY(0), 1, height));

  svg
    .select("#ay-line")
    .attr("x1", clamp(newX(0), 1, width))
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", clamp(newX(0), 1, width))
    .attr("y2", height);

  /* NEW CODE */
  /* Horizontal axis label alignment */
  svg.selectAll("#grid-x .tick").attr("transform", function (d) {

    var t = this.getAttribute("transform");
    var translate = t
      .substring(t.indexOf("(") + 1, t.indexOf(")"))
      .split(",");
    var bb = this.childNodes[1].getBBox(); // child is text element

    var y = newY(0);

    if (y < 0) {
      /* label will be positioned at top of the screen */
      y = bb.height;
    } else if (y >= height - bb.height - 8) { /* 8 is the tick padding */
      /* label will be positioned at bottom of the screen */
      y = height - (bb.height);
    } else {
      /* label will be positioned somewhere in the middle of the screen */
      y = y + bb.height;
    }

    /* update text (childNode) y position with new calculated value */
    d3.select(this.childNodes[1]).attr("y", y)

    return t;
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? I didn't really get it. It seems to work really smoothly?

Comment: All the labels need to be aligned to the axis lines when the axes are in the middle of the chart instead of always remaining at the top and left side of the chart. So when the x-axis is in the middle of the chart the labels should also be positioned in the middle and just a little bit above the x-axis line!

It's the text labels positioning I'm more concerned about

Comment: Ahh now I think I got it. like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYQwc.png (axes labels follow the axis center lines themselves?)

Comment: Yes, that's correct! Should have thought of that ideal output. Thanks very much!